# Data recovery on HP ProLiant ML350 G5 on RAID 1

Tags: hardware-raid

The motherboard in the server in question is dead. How can I recover the data on the RAID 1 drives?

Answer (score 2):

You should just need to put the disks into a similar model server.

Comment: Indeed - get the Hardware sorted and you'll be good to go. That said, with RAID1 - just plug the disk into anything and it'll read as a normal drive.